# find the index of largest, 2nd largest or third largest in a row of multidimensional array pyhton

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let say I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,4,6,2,5],[3,2,7,12,1],[8,5,3,1,4],[6,10,2,4,9]])
b = numpy.array([0, 1, 4])
```

now, I want to first search for the index of the max value in a specific row (just say second row `a[1,:]`), I have another array `b` with some numbers in it and if the index of the max value is present as an element in the other `b`, i use that index number for some more calculation. If the index of max value from a row of `a` is not present as an element in `b`, I need to look for the index of the 2nd largest number, and if that index value is present in `b` as an element, i go for it otherwise look for the index of third largest number and so on. I do not want to sort the array `a`.

In the above example, I have `[3,2,7,12,1]` in the second row.The index of the max number is 3 but that 3 is not present in b, then index of 2nd largest is 2, which is also not present in b, then i look for the index of third largest which is 0 and that is present in b. So I then assign 0 to a new variable. Any quick and fast way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output do you expect for your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that scales well for generic ndarrays -

```
def maxindex(a, b, fillna=-1):
    sidx = a.argsort(-1)
    m = np.isin(sidx,b)
    idx = m.shape[-1] - m[...,::-1].argmax(-1) - 1
    out = np.take_along_axis(sidx,idx[...,None],axis=-1).squeeze()
    return np.where(m.any(-1), out, fillna)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  6,  2,  5],
       [ 3,  2,  7, 12,  1],
       [ 8,  5,  3,  1,  4],
       [ 6, 10,  2,  4,  9]])

In [84]: b
Out[84]: array([0, 1, 4])

In [85]: maxindex(a, b) # all rows
Out[85]: array([4, 0, 0, 1])

In [86]: maxindex(a[1], b) # second row
Out[86]: array([0])
```

3D case -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[[ 1,  4,  6,  2,  5],
        [ 3,  2,  7, 12,  1],
        [ 8,  5,  3,  1,  4],
        [ 6, 10,  2,  4,  9]],

       [[ 1,  4,  6,  2,  5],
        [ 3,  2,  7, 12,  1],
        [ 8,  5,  3,  1,  4],
        [ 6, 10,  2,  4,  9]]])

In [106]: maxindex(a, b)
Out[106]: 
array([[4, 0, 0, 1],
       [4, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: HI Divakar, I cannot test your code because I get the follwoing error. module 'numpy' has no attribute 'take_along_axis'. Although I am importing numpy as np. any idea?

Comment: @HT121 That's a new addition to NumPy library. Can you update your NumPy?

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. Should be possible.

Comment: i could not manage to upgrade numpy. but I am sure if I have the updated version, i should have the desired output. Thanks for that. I also tried myself to get the right output.  I manage to get it work using the following code:
`i = np.argsort(a[1,:])[::-1]`
`c = [x for x in i if x in b]`
`print('intersection is ',c[0])`

Comment: @HT121 What version do you have?

Comment: I have numpy version 1.13.3.

Comment: @HT121 Well that's an old version and it doesn't support that function.

Comment: @HT121 In the meantime, you can simply download [`this file - shape-base.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/v1.15.1/numpy/lib/shape_base.py) and then import with - `from shape_base import take_along_axis`. It's a standalone file.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, if you need to keep the index from `a`:

```
res = b[a[:, b].argmax(1)]

array([4, 0, 0, 1])
```

Alternatively:

```
a[:, np.delete(np.arange(a.shape[1]), b)] = a.min()
res = a.argmax(1)

array([4, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

If the index of a masked array is sufficient:

```
res = a[:, b].argmax(1)

array([2, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @user3483203, Ah, well, I've updated, I *think* I get what OP means now.